# Ubuntu 20.04 - Wireless card and boot issues

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, 20.04

A brief summary of what I've done: I tried to install 18.04 on my laptop yesterday, everything went smoothly, dual boot was working perfectly with Windwows 10, all good. I come back this morning and boot up the computer log in to Ubuntu and my wireless card is not recognized, no wifi icon on the notifications tray, I tried to open the network settings and my wireless connection was still listed as a previously used network, note that the installation process was done using wifi and I used the system briefly after installing it, installed couple of updates/packages, etc.

I tried installing 20.04 thinking it might have been a weird bug on that version, finished installing it, rebooted and the same issue again. Found a couple of posts noting to install iwlwifi, did that, rebooted but same result. Found another post about disabling "secure boot" from the BIOS, did that and now GRUB seems to have been blocked since after restart I no longer see the GRUB screen but boot straight into windows instead, which is what I'm using to be able to post this issue/question.

Edit: Managed to boot back into Ubuntu by changing BIOS settings back defaults and then changing the "OS Boot device" option to point to the Ubuntu partition, managed to take a couple of screenshots:
[network setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kesrw.png)
[software updates/additional drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38KIV.png)

Any suggestions/advice? any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this by disabling the use of additional drivers by selecting "do not use the device" that made wifi work again. I'm not sure why/how that works, but in case anybody out there faces the same problem, you may want to try that.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a typical issue of using the wrong driver version.

I had a similar issue with my Lenovo Y-700. Installing the default recommend driver using the terminal was a no go. Later when I looked into it my Wi-Fi driver was completely different from what version the terminal downloaded.

Sadly, if no-one bothered to make an easy to install version; that usually means you will have to search for the right one, compile from source (assuming it even supports the latest linux kernel). Then load it using

```
sudo modprobe <compiled_binary_of_your_driver>
```

You are probably better off, the way you are and use the pre-installed one by 20.04.